# Browser is showing the text contents of a file instead of the rendered HTML contents of a file

Tags: html

I'm a rookie in webpage development working on my first webpage. I wrote some `HTML` code in a text editor and saved it as an `HTML` file. However, when I open it in my browser, I only see the plain `HTML` text instead of the table. Can anyone help me with this?

The following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <CENTER>
            <TABLE border=2>
                <CAPTION>My Homework</CAPTION>
                <TR>
                    <TD>Link to Homework #1</TD>
                    <TD>Link to Homework #2</TD>
                <TR>
                    <TD>Link to Homework #3</TD>
                    <TD>Link to Homework #4</TD>
                <TR>
                    <TD>Link to Homework #5</TD>
                    <TD>Link to Homework #6</TD>
                <TR>
                    <TD>Link to Homework #7</TD>
                    <TD>Link to Homework #8</TD>
            </TABLE>
        </CENTER>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_save_html_files_from_textedit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to closing the `<TR>`'s with `</TR>`'s make sure you are saving the file with an extension that indicates it's an HTML file. page.html, page.htm etc.

So you are using TextEdit on Mac. Sounds like you might want to read [this](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_save_html_files_from_textedit.html) to ensure you are saving the file correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much, I think this will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What Andrew said is correct about proper HTML. But all browsers fix slightly broken HTML when they render the page.

From the sounds of the issue, i think you might have a file with 2 extensions e.g.: `test.html.txt`

Make sure in windows, you show **known file type extensions** and the file doesn't have a `.txt` (or any other extension besides `.htm` or `.html`) at the end of it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I'm using mac and I double checked the file name, the only extension is ".html". I also added the </TR> back, still the same problem. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you opening it in? Is the icon for the file the icon for Html?

Comment: I tried firefox and chrome and I do have the icon for html. I just tried the same thing in Windows. Open a text file, copy the code there and save it as html file and it works. I guess something wrong when I save the file as html in mac, but I really couldn't find what's wrong.

Comment: If you're using TextEdit on mac, double check it's saving as plain text, not rich text.

Comment: if the extension is html, they don't allow me to save as plain text. Actually there's an option which is saving as webpage(html), I used that and it gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML editor you are using may be translating what you type in as HTML  - that is, when you type <html> , it becomes something like: &lt;html&gt;

Try opening up the file is a simple text editor to see if this is happening.